# AWS Workbench Creation with all the data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, aws-sdk, aws-cli

We have created a Windows Workspace in AWS Server and installed all the required packages to that server and we tried to clone the Workspace. We Created a image from that Workspace and created a bundle and through that bundle we created a new Workspace.  Now the issue is we got the same exact copy of the Workspace but the data inside the Workspace was not get copied.  Can any one share me the steps to create Workspaces including all the data from another workspaces.

Comment: What is a "Windows Workbench"? Are you talking about AWS Workspaces?

Comment: Yes its and aws windows workspace